# Hydra not matching password provided in file

Tags: password-cracking, hydra

I was pen-testing my TP-Link router yesterday and tried performing a Hydra attack on it. I wrote the following line on the terminal:

```
hydra -l admin -p passwords.txt 192.168.0.1 http
```

The username and password for the router is **admin** and the second password provided in the passwords.txt file is **admin** but the output is:

```
1 of 1 target completed, 0 valid passwords found
```

Comment: Try capitalizing the `-P` flag in the command. What it was doing prior was reading the string "passwords.txt" as a single password rather than utilizing it as a wordlist.

Comment: Should I delete this question tough? I don't think it would contribute anything to the community as it is a mere typo?

Comment: It's up to you or the moderators. Glad you got it working!

Comment: waymobetta, next time put that into an answer (like I did now). The questions should remain and have an answer since it can help other people also. I +'ed your comment since its a correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hydra parameters are case-sensitive.

In your specific situation, **-p** is used as password input parameter, while **-P** is used as input for reading a file (Official syntax: [-p PASS|-P FILE] ).